# Audio stream on Safari iOS does not play (MediaSource vs ManagedMediaSource?)

Tags: webkit, media-source, mobile-webkit

**Symptom**

Audio streaming plays on all browsers except on Safari on iOS.
I suspect that the issues comes from `MediaSource` that isn't supported on iOS, so I tried an implementation using `ManagedMediaSource`, without much luck though.

Any idea of what's wrong?

**Code and tests**

```js
let ms;

if ('ManagedMediaSource' in window) { // DOES NOT PLAY ON WEBKIT
    let MediaSource = window.ManagedMediaSource;

    ms = new MediaSource();
    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
        let sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('audio/mpeg');

        // Read and play the audio data chunk by chunk
        let reader = response.body.getReader();
        let readChunk = async () => {
            let {
                value,
                done
            } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
                ms.endOfStream();
            } else {
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
                await new Promise(resolve => sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', resolve, {
                    once: true
                }));
                readChunk();
            }
        };
        readChunk();
    });

    audio.srcObject.disableRemotePlayback = true;
    audio.srcObject.srcObject = ms;
} else {             // PLAYS ON ALL BROWSERS EXCEPT Safari on iOS
    ms = new MediaSource();
    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
        let sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('audio/mp4');

        // Read and play the audio data chunk by chunk
        let reader = response.body.getReader();
        let readChunk = async () => {
            let {
                value,
                done
            } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
                ms.endOfStream();
            } else {
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
                await new Promise(resolve => sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', resolve, {
                    once: true
                }));
                readChunk();
            }
        };
        readChunk();
    });
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms);
    audio.srcObject = null;
}
audio.play()
```

Comment: 1) I note that attachment to the audio tag is different for the top block compared to the second.  I have no syntactic difference between MS and MMS in my own code.
2) Safari is brutal on starting with a gesture.  It might be hanging you. 
3) If the phone is in silent mode, you will get no audio from this code.